# argmin with logic statements [solved]

Tags: statistics, self-learning

Could anyone explain me the equation below? Are we trying the find the T value where the $\theta_T < E_0[t]?$

$T^* = \underset{T}{Argmin} (\theta_T \geq E_0[T])$

I understand how argmin works for an equation like $\underset{x}{Argmin} f(x)$. The question above is not a numeric solution (I think).

I would really appreciate if anyone can provide me guidance on this matter.

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit:

Here are the whole events leading upto the formula. This is taken from Advances in Financial Machine Learning by Marcos Lopez De Prado.

$b_t=\begin{cases}b_{t-1},  & \text{if}\ \Delta p_t = 0 \\ \frac{|\Delta p_t|}{\Delta p_t} ,& \text{if} \Delta p_t \neq 0 \end{cases}    $

- $p_t$ = the price associated with tick t
- $v_t$ = volume associated with tick t

$\theta_T = \sum_{t = 1}^{T}b_t$

T = tick index

$T^* = \underset{T}{Argmin} (\theta_T \geq E_0[T])$

$E_0[T]$  is calculated by exponentially weighted moving average of T

Comment: The statement as it stands is very weird; it may mean that $T^\star$ is the smallest $T$ such that $\theta_T \geq E_0[T]$. However, the notation $E_0[T]$ seems to indicate that $T$ is a random variable; could you give more context?

Comment: You are correct about the T being a random variable. I couldnt believe that answer was obvious! Thanks @RiccardoSvenRisuleo!

Comment: I'm not sure that that's the answer! As a matter of fact if T is a random variable, then $\theta_T$ may also be a random variable; so the whole thing is a bit messy.

Comment: I can share the whole arguments if you would like....

Comment: I'm just guessing, but if $\theta_T$ is a random variable it may be that the expression is missing a probability? Something along the lines of $T^\star = \arg\min_T P(\theta_T \geq E_0[T])$? Sadly, without reading the whole argument it is impossible to give a clear meaning to the statement.

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo, I really appreciate you taking your time. I have added extra detail to see if you can make any sense out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the text around your expression, it seems plausible that $T^\star$ is the smallest $T$ such that $\theta_T \geq E_0[T]$. These are not random variables because they are supposed to be computed at time $T$.

I think that the idea is that $\theta_T$ collects the imbalance in the price; as soon as the imbalance exceeds what we were expecting (so the expected length of the bar, $E_0[T]$), we sample a new bar.

Comment: Thanks! This makes so much sense now!